# Amazon EC2 Security Group with Host / Dynamic IP / DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, firewall, sendgrid

I am seeking some guidance on the best approach to take with EC2 security groups and services with dynamic IP's. I want to make use of services such as SendGrid, Elastic Cloud etc which all use dyanmic IP's over port 80/443. However access to Port 80/443 is closed with the exception of whitelisted IPs. So far the solutions I have found are:

1. CRON Job to ping the service, take IP's and update EC2 Security Group via EC2 API.
2. Create a new EC2 to act as a proxy with port 80/443 open. New server communicates with Sendgrid/ElasticCloud, inspects responses and returns parts to main server.

Are there any other better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please bear in mind that security groups in AWS are [stateful](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups), meaning that, for example, if you open ports `80` and `443` to all destinations (`0.0.0.0/0`) in your *outbound rules*, your EC2 machines will be able to connect to remote hosts and get the response back even if there are no inbound rules for a given IP.

However, this approach works only if the connection is always initiated by your EC2 instance and remote services are just responding. If you require the connections to your EC2 instances to be initiated from the outside, you do need to specify inbound rules in security group(s). If you know a CIDR block of their public IP addresses, that can solve the problem as you can specify it as a destination in security group rule. If you don't know IP range of the hosts that are going to reach your machines, then access restriction at network level is not feasible and you need to implement some form of authorisation of the requester.

P.S. Please also bear in mind that there is a soft default limit of [50 inbound or outbound rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups) per security group.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, didn't know that. Unfortunately I think there are webhooks that the EC2 will need to listen for and I don't have a CIDR block for Sendgrid. :/ Should I look for alternative software firewalls?

Comment: @calh27 I believe, listening should be fine since the connection is initiated by EC2. But needs to be tested, of course.

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified it's more of a script awaiting a json notification rather than sockets listening.